# put Json just in one field in a new table in sql

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have to write the code that create a table in just one field then put the out put of my Json into that table, but I don't know how could I put the out put my Json in just one field.
here is my Json code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Food_tbl
FOR JSON AUTO
```

the output of the Json is like this:

```
[{"FID":1,"Fname":"cake","Fcount":5,"FDate":"2020-02-13","Fregion":"UK"},...]
```

output:

in new tabel that store in database like this:

```
|     JsonOutPut                                                                   |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   [{"FID":1,"Fname":"cake","Fcount":5,"FDate":"2020-02-13","Fregion":"UK"},...]  |
```

Comment: Your output and expected output look the same to me. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my answer, here is my code:

```
DECLARE @OneRowJson NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT * 
                                    FROM FoodSara_tbl
                                    FOR Json AUTO)
SELECT @OneRowJson OneRow INTO OneFieldJsonFood
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This Dude:

```
Select @OneRowJson UniqueRow into JasonRow99
```